# Summate using Abel method series $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin{\theta n} $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

Summate using Abel method series $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin{\theta n} $.

For Abel sum we should consider functional series $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin{\theta n} \cdot x^{n-1}$, find the sum $ S(x) $ and count $ \lim_{x \to 1-0} S(x) $.

I know that if there is a sum of Cesaro, sum of Abel also exists and equals to the sum of Cesaro. I obtained that sum of Cesaro (if I didn't mistake) is $ \cot{\frac{\theta}{2}} / 2 $. Hence the Abel sum $ \cot{\frac{\theta}{2}} / 2 $ too. But how to obtain Abel sum without using this theorem.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you know the exponential form of sine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Euler's formulas: $\sin n\theta = \dfrac{e^{in\theta}-e^{-in\theta}}{2i}$, so
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin(n\theta)\,x^{n-1} &=
\frac{x^{-1}}{2i} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \Big( (xe^{i\theta})^n- (xe^{-i\theta})^n \Big) \\
&= \frac{1}{2i} \Big( \frac{e^{i\theta}}{1-xe^{i\theta}} - \frac{e^{-i\theta}}{1-xe^{-i\theta}} \Big) 
\end{align}
(for $|x| < 1$) using the sum of two geometric series. Letting $x \to 1^-$, we get
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2i} \Big( \frac{e^{i\theta}}{1-e^{i\theta}} - \frac{e^{-i\theta}}{1-e^{-i\theta}} \Big) &=
\frac{1}{2i} \Big( \frac{e^{i\theta}}{1-e^{i\theta}} - \frac{1}{e^{i\theta}-1} \Big) \\
&= \frac{1}{2i} \, \frac{1+e^{i\theta}}{1-e^{i\theta}} \\
&= \frac{i}{2} \, \frac{e^{i\theta/2}+e^{-i\theta/2}}{e^{i\theta/2}-e^{-i\theta/2}} = \frac12 \cot \frac{\theta}{2}.
\end{align}

Comment: Why not save a bit of space and simply write $\sin x=\text{Im}(e^{ix})$?

Answer (score 4):

For $|x|<1$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n-1}\sin n\theta&=\frac1x\text{Im}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n}e^{in\theta}\right)\\\\
&=\text{Im}\left(\frac{e^{i\theta}}{1-xe^{i\theta}}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{\sin \theta}{x^2-2x\cos \theta+1}
\end{align}$$

Thus,

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 1^-}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n-1}\sin n\theta\right)&=\frac{\sin \theta}{2-2\cos \theta}\\\\
&=\frac{\sin(2\theta/2)}{4\sin^2(\theta/2)}\\\\
&=\frac{2\sin (\theta/2)\cos(\theta/2)}{4\sin^2(\theta/2)}\\\\
&=\frac12 \cot(\theta/2)
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: So posting first and with a more efficient way forward gets dismissed without the best vote?  Curious.